# adsense-pencilblue initialising of plugin is failing

Tags: plugins, adsense, pencilblue

I’m using **adsense-pencilblue** Plugin, when it goes to the live site, it is showing an error message while I'm configuring it. Screenshot is attached of the error message.

[image: Error Message Screenshot]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: every time you install a new plugin to Pencilblue, don't forget to remove " *.git " files.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `*.git` files from your plugin directory by running
`rm -rf .git` in **adsense-pencilblue** directory then deploying again. It will solve your problem on live site.

Comment: You can upvote and accept the answer as well by clicking the tick icon :P